# False Negative Probability of a probabilistic black box function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, quantum-mechanics, sampling

Suppose we have black-box access to a function that returns the roots of some unknown 5-degree polynomial in each invocation. (So there will be 5 roots.)

But we also know that the function is probabilistic. In each invocation, it returns a true root with 0.8 probability, and it outputs a random value with 0.2 probability.

Say we do r invocation of the algorithm, and we are tasked to learn the roots of the unknown polynomial with very high confidence $\delta$ (= 0.9).

Now, what is the probability of a false negative -- not identifying one or more of the true roots of the unknown polynomial from the output of the function invocations?

I thought that after r invocations, we could draw a frequency histogram and identify the correct roots, but there could be two scenarios where we can have false negatives:

1. When one of the random values is also outputted too many times and hence pretending to be a correct root. This particular random value will be a false positive, but since we are going to select only 5 values from the histogram, hence we will not be picking a correct root and hence contributing toward a false negative scenario. In this case, the probability of a false negative should be $\frac{0.2}{N-5}^{r/5}$
2. Say t roots among the 5 roots are clearly visible from the histogram, but the remaining 5-t roots appear with almost the same frequency as the other random values.

I am not sure how to calculate the probability in Case 2 above and also the total false negative probability.

Comment: When the black box chooses to output a correct root, is the correct root chosen at random from the set of 5 roots? Because if the function always outputs the same correct root and any random number when it is wrong, there is no way to ascertain all the roots of the polynomial.

Comment: If the random value is drawn from a continuous distribution, the random values will [almost surely] not appear more than once. So it seems this problem is only interesting if the random value is drawn from a distribution with a discrete component.

Comment: @sudeep5221 Yes, when the black box chooses to output a correct root, it chooses a correct root at random from among the set of 5 roots.

Comment: Finding an exact formula for the probability is impossible without more information about the distribution when the oracle is malicious.  OTOH, one can bound the probability via the multinomial distribution.